# Run jQuery script after AJAX call on Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to run the script below on Woocommerce checkout page to change shipping methods. The issue is that the Woocommerce checkout review order table use AJAX so my script doesn't work. How can I run my script after AJAX calls ?

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function () { 
  if($(".variation-Livraison p:contains(A domicile)")) {
    $("#shipping_method").addClass('disable');
  }
});
```

URL of the website https://festichablais.fr/checkout/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Here is a list of js hooks that you can use - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend